# MATLAB: Why the output values are the same from x3, x4, x5 etc in Cramer's rule code

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I have the following code for Cramer's rule which works perfectly but for system of linear equation of order greater than 3, the value of x3, x4, x5 etc are the same (the fault is not from the questions I used but I believe it is from the code). Please can someone help me out.

```
  function x=cramer_rule(A,b)
        A=input('matrix A =');
         b=input('vector b =');
         n=size(A,1);
          m=size(A,2);
      if n~=m
           fprintf(1, '\n The matrix is not square! \n');
            x=[];
      else
  detA=det(A);
if det(A)~=0
     x=zeros(n,1);
    for j=1:n
        if j~=1 && j~=n
            Ab=[A(:,1:j-1) b A(:,j+1:n)];
        elseif j==1
            Ab=[b A(:,2:n)];
        end
        x(j)=det(Ab)/detA;
    end %for j=1:n
   else 
     fprintf(1, '\n The matrix A has a zero determinant \n');
     x=[];
   end % if det(A)~=0
 end % if n~=m
```

For example, the matrix A =[2,5,-9,3;5,6,-4,2;3,-4,2,7;11,7,4,-8] and b =[151;103;16;-32] suppose to give output of x1=3,  x2=5,  x3=-11,  x4=7  but I got my x3 and x4 to be -11

Your suggestion(s) and contribution(s) will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `b` matrix should be a column vector instead of a row vector.

Now your matrix b is 1x3 (should be 3x1), and matrix A is 3x3.

when you do `Ab=[b A(:,2:n)]` you are trying to horizontally concatenate a 1 x 3 matrix `b` with a 3 x (n-1) matrix `A(:,2:n)`.

You can see that this will never work for any value of n, since the number of rows do not match.

Try to run the code with  `A =[1,4,5;4,2,5;-3,3,-1]` and `b =[2;3;1]`

By the way, you should better indent your code. It's unclear where the conditionals start and end.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction. it works perfectly. When i use it for higher order, my X3, X4 etc are the same. Does that mean it works for only order three?   For instance matrix A =[2,5,-9,3;5,6,-4,2;3,-4,2,7;11,7,4,-8] and vector b =[151;103;16;-31] suppose to give the value of  x1=3, x2=5, x3=-11 and x4=7     but I got  3.1172,  4.8892,   -11.0670 and   -11.0670 ( why   -11.0670 twice which is wrong)
     Any reason for this anomaly?